# How to load csv files for ybar stacked in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, luatex

I'd like to load a csv for a ybar stacked diagramm.
How can this be done?
Here is a minimal sample including sample filecontents to be used in the diagram:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
Size    A   B   C
X   30  30  47
Y   1   2   3
Z   69  68  50
\end{filecontents}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  ybar stacked,
  bar width = 1cm,
  enlargelimits=0.15,
  legend style={at={(0.5,-0.40)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
  ylabel={\%-Anteile},
  symbolic x coords={A, B, C},
  xtick=data,
  x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east,yshift=-0.3cm},
  yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\%}
]
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(A,30) (B,30) (C,47)};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(A,1) (B,2) (C,3)};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(A,69) (B,68) (C,50)};
\legend{X, Y, Z}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load the text file into a `pgfplotstable` table, and transpose it. Then you just do `\addplot table[x=Size,y=X] {\transposedtable};`. Add three separate `\addplot`s, or use a loop, as in the example below. You don't need to add the `ybar` option to every `\addplot` when you have `ybar` or `ybar stacked` in the `axis` options.

Unrelated comments:

`xcolor` is already loaded by `tikz`, which is loaded by `pgfplots`, so you don't actually have to explicitly load it. And the syntax for `\addplot` is `\addplot coordinates`, not `\addplot plot coordinates`. (Which tutorial teaches that anyway?)

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xcolor} %loaded by pgfplots
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % also loads pgfplots
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
Size    A   B   C
X   30  30  47
Y   1   2   3
Z   69  68  50
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread{data.csv}\mydata
% transpose table
\pgfplotstabletranspose[
   % use first column as header
   colnames from=Size,
   % first cell/first row is changed to "colnames", change back to "Size"
   input colnames to=Size]\transposeddata\mydata
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  ybar stacked,
  bar width = 1cm,
  enlargelimits=0.15,
  legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)}, % changed -0.40 to =0.15
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
  ylabel={\%-Anteile},
  symbolic x coords={A, B, C},
  xtick=data,
  x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east,yshift=-0.3cm},
  yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\%}
]

\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{X,Y,Z}{ %loop over the three columns
  \addplot table[x=Size,y=#1] {\transposeddata};
}

\legend{X, Y, Z}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```